# filtering and joining two tables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use the promotions and transactions data, and compute the total sales for all products that were on a display in the front of the store (display_location = 1) but I keep getting this error

```
Error in `auto_copy()`:
! `x` and `y` must share the same src.
ℹ set `copy` = TRUE (may be slow).
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% arrange(desc(total_sales))
 5. dplyr:::inner_join.data.frame(., get_transactions, by = "product_id")
 6. dplyr::auto_copy(x, y, copy = copy)
```

I tried the following:

```
get_promotions() %>%
  filter(display_location == 1) %>%
  inner_join(get_transactions, by = "product_id" ) %>%
  summarize(total_sales = sum(sales_value)) %>%
  arrange(desc(total_sales))
```

Comment: Please make your issue reproducible by providing an example of the data frames you are using that are causing this error.

Comment: added @Phil
```{r} 
library(completejourney)
library(dplyr)

get_transactions()
demographics
get_promotions()
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `()` to `get_transactions` because it is a function. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(completejourney) 
library(dplyr) 

get_promotions() %>%
  filter(display_location == 1) %>%
  inner_join(get_transactions(), by = "product_id" ) %>%
  summarize(total_sales = sum(sales_value)) %>%
  arrange(desc(total_sales))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   total_sales
#>         <dbl>
#> 1   67430178.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>